# Ubuntu freezes on purple screen [dualboot, nvidia graphics]

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia

I recently tried dual booting Ubuntu on my laptop. I followed [this](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) guide and was able to successfully install and login to ubuntu. However now when I try to login, I get stuck at a purple screen with no login option. I tried looking around online and it seems like the problem lies with the nvidia graphics card.

I then found [this](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/) guide and followed it. It worked at first. After adding "nomodeset" I was able to login. The desktop icons were all triple in size and everything looked zoomed in but i was in. From there I updated the drivers through "software and updates" and restarted. Nothing changed. I still get stuck at the purple screen and this time adding nomodeset results in a

> P[some letter and numbers (don't remember exactly)] signature not signed with trusted key

I have secure boot off and fast startup off if that makes any difference.

I then found some other forum post that said to enter recovery mode. I tried that but even recovery mode froze after like two lines of text (or at least I think it froze. I waited ~5mins and other than the two initial lines of text nothing changed. It didn't give me any options or register keyboard presses).

Any ideas? I did "minimal install" for ubuntu i believe if that makes any difference.

Comment: I get this about 20 times over 2 second period during boot but it doesn't seem to effect the machine: `PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key`.

Comment: Is there a way to login in through that? Because in mine it just stays in that terminal like screen with no login popup.

Comment: Disable Secure boot in UEFI as it prevents loading the Nvidia drivers.